# Turtle build:android fails in azuredevops pipeline, what am i missing?

Tags: bash, build, azure-devops, expo, azure-pipelines

I get this error when running turtle build:android

```
turtle[4754] ERROR: Failed to build standalone app
err: ConfigError: The expected package.json path: /Users/runner/work/1/s/<key_alias>/package.json does not exist
```

This is what the script looks like in my .yml

```
turtle setup:ios \ 
  IOS_DIST_P12_PASSWORD=$(IOS_DIST_P12_PASSWORD) \ 
  turtle build:ios -u $(EXPO_CLI_USER) -p $(EXPO_CLI_PASSWORD)\
  --team-id $(APPLE_TEAM_ID) \
  --dist-p12-path ./my-app_dist.p12 \
  --provisioning-profile-path ./myapp.mobileprovision \
  --release-channel deployment

  turtle setup:android \ 
  ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=$(ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD) \ 
  ANDROID_KEY_PASSWORD=$(ANDROID_KEY_PASSWORD) \ 
  turtle build:android -u $(EXPO_CLI_USER) -p $(EXPO_CLI_PASSWORD)\
  --keystore-path ./my-app.jks \
  --keystore-alias $(KEY_ALIAS) \
  -t apk \
  --release-channel deployment
```

I have all the correct information in the yml and all the env variables are defined. Do I also need to run keytool command before i run turtle build? I have already done it for the app in the past and the filepaths are there.

Same issue for ios, it says the path/package.json doesnt exist.

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: I noticed that I was getting a error "command not found" for the variable declarations before the build command, so I removed them (since the variables were saved in the pipeline) and it worked perfectly. Im not sure why I was getting that error because I used the format almost all the docs i found for turtlecli were using.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. "removed the Expo variables in front of the build command" can solve this problem, I added this to answer to help other community members who get the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As a workaround**:
Remove the Expo variables in front of the build command (they were already declared as variables) and it worked fine.

For details, please refer to this [case](https://www.reddit.com/r/azuredevops/comments/jry3if/help_with_turtle_command_in_pipeline/).

In addition, you can try to check whether the `android.package` key is included in the expo object of the `app.json` file

```
{
  "expo": {
    "sdkVersion": "26.0.0",
    "name": "TongPos",
    "description": "your app desc",
    "android": {
      "package": "com.sohagfaruque.tongpos"
    }
  }
}
```